# Python - Want to list file name serially one after another from a given directory

Tags: python-2.7

Here's my code-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
root_dir = 'C:/Users/Files/test' 
# Traverse directory, and list files
for datafiles in os.listdir(root_dir):
    print datafiles
    file_location = os.path.join(root_dir, datafiles)
```

Here, the file_location is storing all the file names in one array. I want it should list me one by one. When I print the file names are printed twice.

The file_location is called by another python script as below-

```
import xlrd
import re
from testdir import file_location

print 'File location = ', file_location
```

The file location is passed as a argument from first program. Worksheet is open

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

My files are getting processed twice. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In `testdir.py` you are iterating over all the files in the directory and printing each filename, but only storing the last one you encounter.

```
for number in [1, 2, 3]:
    print "In loop, number=", number
    lastnumber = number

print "Out of loop"
print "lastnumber =", number
```

output:

```
In loop, number= 1
In loop, number= 2
In loop, number= 3
Out of loop
lastnumber = 3
```

So, you will see each file name displayed as the loop iterates.

In your second script you import this file. Remember that all the code will be run when you import the module, including all the printing. So you'll see the last filename displayed twice - once in the loop and once when you print it in the second script. For the situation as you have described it, your final workbook will be opened, but only for the last file encountered in the loop.

I think that this is a bit of a roundabout way to do what you probably want to do which is to process all the Excel files in a particular directory, which can be done easily with the `glob` module:

```
from glob import glob
import os

root_dir = 'C:/Users/Files/test'
for filename in glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '*.xls')):
    process(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing the file names twice because script `file_location` is being called twice, both on `print 'File location = ', file_location` and on `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)`. Keeping your original implementation, perhaps you want to change the code that generates the file location not to print the files from within, but to return them via a function, something like:

```
import os, xlrd

def file_location(root_dir):
    for datafiles in os.listdir(root_dir):
        files = os.path.join(root_dir, datafiles)
    return files

if __name__=='__main__':
    files = file_location('C:/Users/Files/test')
    print 'File location = ', files
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(files)
```

Call the code above `test.py` and try running `python test.py`.